# Java ee web: how to deal with several controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web

I'm new in java ee web and i use MVC pattern to build my application. I want your help.

> Imagine this scenario:

**1. Controller items**

2. Model items (extract all items from database)
3. View items

**4. Controller item detail**

5. Model item detail (extract a specific item with an id)
6. View item detail

> What i want

Actually I'm stopped because I don't know how to make a controller to dispatch the treatment to other controller.

Using the previous scenario, i want to build a dispatcher or a special controler to drives my controllers.

This dispatcher must call the **1.Controller items**. The called controller provide a list of all item with a checkbox to permit selection of one item.
The dispatcher receive the answer from the **1.Controller items** and call the **4.Controller item detail**. The called controller provide a detail for one item.

Thanks to help me

Comment: Server context path redirects to a specific controller. Which MVC implementation are you using or rather how are you trying to develop your application on MVC. Any code sample or references. You can have a look at Spring MVC. This is a very easy implementation. Annotations are big help and makes the life easy. Spring Dispatcher servlet takes care of directing the request to the specific controller out of many controllers.

Comment: Have a look at this example http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: you would create two controllers one for passing o the view list of items and the second will retrieve an id passed in the get request and this controller passes to a new view the informations about that item do you want to see an implementation??